# perl sort 2d array with references

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I am somewhat new to perl so please bear with me. I've exhausted all possible solutions I could find so far.

Let's say I have some hats with some measurements that are filled elsewhere. And I want to sort them based on a certain column. I try to do this using perl's "sort" but I don't get them to actually sort. I believe the problem is that I'm confused on references. The code below is what I'm working with at the moment.

```
my @hat1 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
my @hat2 = [4, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2];
my @hat3 = [9, 8, 9, 3, 4, 4];
#eventually work with unknown number of hats

my @binToSort = (\@hat1,\@hat2,\@hat3);

my @binSorted = sort { $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] } @binToSort;

for my $ref (@binSorted){
    for my $inner (@$ref){
        print "@$inner\n";
    }
}
```

As of now it prints out the unsorted array values:

```
3 4 5 6 7 8
4 6 5 1 1 2
9 8 9 3 4 4
```

But I want to be able to arrive at:

```
4 6 5 1 1 2
9 8 9 3 4 4
3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I feel like this is a simple problem but I can't figure out the right way to do it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: turn on warnings with `use warnings;` and you'll get `Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>)` Think about why `$a->[4]` and `$b->[4]` might be undefined.

Comment: and if necessary, add `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@binToSort;`

Comment: I see the warnings now, thanks. And `print Dumper \@binToSort;` gives me `$VAR1 = [[[3,4,5,6,7,8]],[[4,6,5,1,1,2]],[[9,8,9,3,4,4]]];` (in column form). Those double brackets... that's a red flag right?

Comment: Yes, it is a red flag, https://eval.in/366831

Comment: That's right. Now you can trace the execution of the `sort`. In the first iteration, `$a` will be `[[3,4,5,6,7,8]]` (a reference to an array containing one element) and `$b` will be `[[4,6,5,1,1,2]]` (another reference to an array containing one element).

Comment: aha! I got it working. Thank you for pointing me to where the problem was, in how I was filling the array. I'll add an answer with the functioning code.

Comment: @imomushi8: Perl *does* treat that as a one-dimensional array. The problem isn't that you're taking references to the `@hat` arrays, it's that you're initialising them to have a *single* element each which is an array reference. `print Dumper \@hat1` to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
my $hat1 = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ];
my $hat2 = [ 4, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2 ];
my $hat3 = [ 9, 8, 9, 3, 4, 4 ];

#eventually work with unknown number of hats

my @binToSort = ( $hat1, $hat2, $hat3 );

my @binSorted = sort { $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] } @binToSort;

for my $ref (@binSorted) {
    for my $inner ( @{$ref} ) {
        print "$inner";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Or

```
my @hat1 = ( 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 );
my @hat2 = ( 4, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2 );
my @hat3 = ( 9, 8, 9, 3, 4, 4 );

#eventually work with unknown number of hats

my @binToSort = ( \@hat1, \@hat2, \@hat3 );

my @binSorted = sort { $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] } @binToSort;

for my $ref (@binSorted) {
    for my $inner ( @{$ref} ) {
        print "$inner";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! And I appreciate seeing two different ways to do it.